# Substitution in the DE $y' \tan(y)+4x^3\cos(y)=2x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

I have to solve the differential equation,
$$ y' \tan(y)+4x^3\cos(y)=2x$$

I propose the substitution $u=\cos(y)$, so $$u'=-y'\sin(y) \\\Rightarrow \sin(y) = -\dfrac{u'}{y'} \\\Rightarrow \tan(y)=\dfrac{\sin(y)}{\cos(y)}=-\dfrac{u'}{y'}\dfrac{1}{u}$$

Then substituting into the DE, gives

$$-y' \dfrac{u'}{y'}\dfrac{1}{u}+4x^3u=2x \\
\Rightarrow 
-\dfrac{u'}{u}+4x^3u=2x \\
\Rightarrow 
u'-4x^3u^2+2xu=0$$

Which clearly, is a Bernoulli equation.

My question is: Is it correct to use the substitution that way?

I have doubts because I have never used a substitution like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible a simplification: divide by $\cos(y)$. You'll have that:

$$y' \sec(y) \tan(y) -2x\sec(y) = -4x^3$$
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\sec(y) -2x\sec(y) = -4x^3$$

Now its directly seen to be a linear differential equation.

And for your question about *substitution*, its fine. It just means you are calling the function by some other *name*. If you prefer, you can just leave it in original form.